# Rails model query from sql

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model, acts-as-taggable-on

I am working on rails 3,

I am writing a logic in rails to fetch the tags related to a tag based on a taggable type. 
How to write the same in rails way from the below sql?

```
 select 
      count(t2.id), 
      t2.id,
      t2.tag_id 
 from taggings t1 
      inner join taggings t2 on (t1.taggable_id = t2.taggable_id and t1.taggable_type = t2.taggable_type ) 
 where t1.tag_id = 2 
 group by(t2.id);
```

**EDIT**

I wrote like

```
tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find_by_name(params[:id])
  join_clause = 'INNER JOIN taggings as t2 ON(t1.taggable_id = t2.taggable_id and t1.taggable_type = t2.taggable_type)'
  select_clause = "DISTINCT t2.tag_id"
  from_clause = 'taggings as t1'
  where_clause = "t1.tag_id = #{tag.id} and t2.tag_id != #{tag.id}"
  group_by_clause = "(t2.id)"
  @related_tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.select(select_clause).joins(join_clause).where(where_clause).from(from_clause).group(group_by_clause).collect do |t|
```

ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(t.tag_id)
end

How to rewrite the same in more rails way.

Comment: Are `taggings t1` and `taggings t2` two different tables? And if so are they Associated in the Rails models?

Comment: @ScottJShea No both are same tables taggings from ActsAsTaggableOn

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I full understand your question but you can either use `find_by_sql` or restructure your query to use Arel through method / scope chaining. For example:

```
Tag.select("count(...)").from("taggings").join("inner join taggings...")
```

Comment: tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find_by_name(params[:id])
  join_clause = 'INNER JOIN taggings as t2 ON(t1.taggable_id = t2.taggable_id and t1.taggable_type = t2.taggable_type)'
  select_clause = "DISTINCT t2.tag_id"
  from_clause = 'taggings as t1'
  where_clause = "t1.tag_id = #{tag.id} and t2.tag_id != #{tag.id}"
  group_by_clause = "(t2.id)"
  related_tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tagging.select(select_clause).joins(join_clause).where(where_clause).from(from_clause).group(group_by_clause).collect do |t|ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(t.tag_id)end
How to rewrite the same in more rails way.